# Unable to run the blink sample for Azure Sphere

Tags: azure, azure-sphere

I am getting the following error (see screenshot) after setting up my Azure Sphere and trying to run the Blink sample. Any ideas?[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNxJT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you put your Sphere device into prep-debug mode?  This step installs a gdb debugger on the device and sets things up so you can sideload applications.

> azsphere device prep-debug

Answer (score 0):

I had an `Object reference not found error` while trying to build and **cleaning component cache** resolved the issue.

Also for VS 2017:  folder was

> %USERPROFILE%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_d9d88191\ComponentModelCache

Answer (score -1):

When I'd that error (the same one), I had to clean the visual studio cache.

You can see at this web site. https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/